# Why do we use prepare() in a media player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I am unable to clear myself that why do we need to use prepare() method in Mediaplayer. Why start() independently doesn't work in music players...

Comment: Why do we need to open a file before reading it?

Comment: without opening a file we can't read it but without using prepare() and using only start(), we can use the media player. I am asking this thing. But you crap don't know what to answer. If you cant solve the problem its better to stay away.

Comment: That's an interesting attitude for someone looking for help. I said that because prepare() *is what opens the file*. You can't call start() before prepare() unless you use one of the create() methods, because they call prepare() for you. Read the documentation for MediaPlayer and it shows a very nice state diagram. There's no "problem" to solve here.

Comment: thanx 4 d help.. You could have explained this before instead of taunting. That would have been better. Because people here are not to enjoy. If someone is asking then he/she might be in serious trouble. Anyhow..

Comment: For the record, I wasn't taunting. I was comparing prepare() to opening a file. You call them for the same reason. It came out short because I was typing on my phone. Also, the question is easily answered by looking at the docs, and I didn't feel it was worth going into extreme detail.

Comment: actually i am doing on-job training in android. So I was looking for details for what I have read so that I can crack the interviews.

Answer (score 2):

The `prepare` method collects metadata about the file or stream to be played, which may be necessary for proper function of the player itself and related components (like UI). The fact that you can call `prepare` and `prepareAsync` separately from calling `setDataSource` or `start` is simply a means of allowing the developer control over when and how things happen to suit his/her particular circumstance. Particularly for streaming media, preparation may take a significant amount of time, and so doing things the same way all the time will not be ideal in every situation.

Answer (score 1):

suppose if you want doing some work that can be possible when media player is collecting infoemation then what you do. if start() work for both what happened if media player is collecting information about media. this will be treated as playing and it crashes completely. these are the states and has there works.